# Build email string from calculated column in list

Tags: 2010, list, item

I need to launch a new email when someone clicks an item in a list that is displayed as html.  So the email will pop up with a mailto:, subject and body.  But the body should be a string of text and if possible resolving the user's name but not crucial, something like "John Smith is enquiring about " then following the text it would have the contents of column1, column2.

I have this code below but it enters the word 'spec' into the email and not the value of the item I clicked through from.  This is entered into a calulated column in a sharepoint 2010 list.

```
=CONCATENATE("<a href=mailto:me@me.com?SUBJECT=Hello&BODY=This%20is%20the%20body%20BUY%20[Spec]>LINK</a>")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax should be

```
=CONCATENATE("<a href=mailto:me@me.com?SUBJECT=Hello&BODY=This%20is%20the%20body%20BUY%20",[Spec],">LINK</a>")
```

Read more on the syntax - https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/CONCATENATE-function-5b0392b2-94ef-49ea-8532-4fdd3a69d362

Comment: Thanks for this, I've now hit the problem of trying to calculate a column that has multiple lines of text so will look at the workaround for that

Comment: I have a couple of columns where not all the data is coming back due to a comma or a £ or $ sign.  How can I include the whole line regardless of what characters it contains?